# Javascript: HTML CODE in javascript into a frame

Tags: javascript, html, frame, document.write

I'm trying to put a HTML code into a frame.

Out of frame I have used: `document.write` and into?

The frame is:

```
var frameTwitter = document.getElementById('FrameTwitter');
```

Comment: If the frame is not on the same domain as your site, then you cannot touch it.

Comment: but the frame is on the same domain...

Comment: How are you trying to edit the frame?  What problem are you having?

Comment: I'm trying to do *frame.document.write('html code here');* but when I run it, this frame appears empty

Comment: In what browser are you doing that?

Comment: IE and Chrome. I'm getting the following error: *Cannot call method 'write' of undefined *

Answer (score 3):

In order to write to an iFrame, you need to get its `contentWindow` or `contentDocument`.

```
var frameTwitter = document.getElementById('FrameTwitter'),
    frameDocument = frameTwitter.contentWindow || frameTwitter.contentDocument;
frameDocument = frameDocument.document || frameDocument;

frameDocument.write('<p>Hello World!</p>');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/8Ekrs/1/

**UPDATE**:
You can also use `window.frames` to get the iFrame's `window` object.

```
var frameDocument = window.frames.FrameTwitter.document;
frameDocument.write('<p>Hello World!</p>');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/8Ekrs/2/

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the postmessage API
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Rocket Hazmat is also correct

*Normally, scripts on different pages are only allowed to access each other if and only if the pages which executed them are at locations with the same protocol (usually both http), port number (80 being the default for http), and host (modulo document.domain being set by both pages to the same value)*

Comment: If the domains don't match exactly, don't you have to set `document.domain` to the least common denominator?

Comment: I think you don't have to, the message will be sent anyway if the domain is 'similar'. you can control on the recipient side which origins to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using 2 files that are on the same domain this should work. It's probably ideal to use a relative path on the `iframe` since you've got to match domains, protocols & ports or this will stop working.

**MainPage.html**

```
<iframe src="Frame.html" id="FrameTwitter"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var frame = document.getElementById('FrameTwitter');
frame.writeInto('Some text here');
</script>
```

**Frame.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function writeInto(str) {
    document.writeln(str);
}
</script>
```

That way you can set up the functionality you need for `Frame.html` within the file, test functionality there without worrying about cross-frame development yet. Then once your features are set up you can fire them from the parent.